# Can pre-compressed refrigerant or other gas be effectively used for air-conditioning?

Tags: temperature, gas

Is it feasible to store a very large quantity of precompressed gas that can later be used for cooling the coils in an air-conditioner?

For example, an aerosol can such as a deodorant has a cooling effect when sprayed on an object. I found that when sprayed on a thermometer, it registers a temperature of around 18 degrees Celsius. Is there a reason why this concept doesn't scale to a practical application? For example, a very large deodrant can sprayed on coils and then a fan blows on the coils to cool the air.

Comment: There is a big environmental impact for your proposed process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compressed-gas release air coolers as you propose are very common- they are extremely simple and light in weight. But to have enough capacity to run the system for extended periods of time, you need a huge, unwieldy compressed gas container. For these reasons, compressed gas-release refrigeration systems (called *Coleman cycle* coolers) are used where system weight must be minimized, and even then they do not run on tanks of compressed air- they use compressed air that is furnished by air compressors that run continuously. All big passenger jets use Coleman cycle air conditioning systems powered by bleed air taken off the compressor stages or their engines.